# Stored procedure : Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I lack experience building stored procedures and have encountered this error that I cannot understand the reasoning behind :

> [2015-09-29 01:01:55] [22001][1292] Data truncation: Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '5609d3e6c89be'

The value '5609d3e6c89be' is the "FlightID".

My stored procedure code :

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS initFlight;
CREATE PROCEDURE initFlight (flightid VARCHAR(50))
 BEGIN

  -- rules, player should only fly if not in jail, not in missions
  -- and is in the city the flight will take off from
  DECLARE fname VARCHAR(50); -- flight name
  DECLARE depart int; -- city number of departure
  DECLARE dest int; -- city number of destination

   -- assign values to our variables
  select flightname, source_airport, destination_airport
  into fname, depart, dest
  from airport_flights where id = flightID;

  -- show in console the variable values for debugging
  -- select concat(" fname: ", fname, " depart: ", depart, " dest: ", dest);

  -- set players flying means p.live = '-1'
  update `[players]` as p set p.live = '-1' where p.id in (
    select id from airport_tickets where flight = flightID
  ) and p.live = depart;

   -- insert into alerts a message for players boarding the flight (are in the city of departure)
  insert into player_alerts (alert_text, player_id)
    select concat("Boarding flight ", fname) as alert_text, p.id as player_id from `[players]` as p
    where p.id in (
      select id from airport_tickets where flight = flightID
    ) and p.live = depart;

   -- insert into alerts a message for players that missed the flight (are not in the city of departure)
  insert into player_alerts (alert_text, player_id)
    select concat("You missed flight ", fname) as alert_text, id as player_id from `[players]` as p
    where p.id in (
      select id from airport_tickets where flight = flightID
    ) and p.live != depart;

   -- stop sales
   update airport_flights set selling_tickets = 0 where id = flightID;

END;
call initFlight('5609d3da016bf');
```

What is happening here? Why is my "string" being coverted into a double and then truncated?

```
airport_flights.id is varchar(50)
airport_flights.source_airport is int(11)
airport_flights.destination_airport is int(11)

airport_tickets.id is varchar(50)
airport_tickets.flight is varchar(50)
airport_tickets.owner_id is int(11)


`[players]`.id is int(11)
`[players]`.live is int(11)
`[players]`.name is varchar(200)

player_alerts.id is int(11)
player_alerts.alert_text is varchar(250)
```

PS: if you need any more information let me know and criticism is as always welcome

Comment: It would help if you put the players table as well.

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26743197/err-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value: **This is one of those really crappy errors that gets thrown that might not have anything to do with the actual problem.** Do know which query in the procedure is getting the error?

Comment: Added player fields now. As far as the query that is erroring out, I have no idea, those queries were made 1 by 1 and then combined into the stored procedure, is there a way to debug this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much head bumping around I found out that the problem was in the sub-queries where I was mixing the airport_tickets.id (varchar) with the player.id (int) when I wanted to match airport_tickets.owner_id with player.id.

I only found this out when removing everything and re-writing it all as a measure of removing any code blindness (when your brain reads what it thinks the code does instead of what is actually written).